# What is the relation of PIE *wers (“to confuse, mix up; to beat, thresh, grind”), *wert ("to turn, to rotate"), and *werb (“to bend, to turn”)?

Tags: phonetics, etymology, proto-indo-european, indo-european, comparative-linguistics

From *wers we get English *war, worse, worst*.

From *wert we get English *versus, verse, version, vertex, vortex, vertical, revert, invert, divert,..., worth, -ward, weird*.

From *werb/p we get English *warp, wrap, re**verb**erate, en**velop**(e), de**velop**, over**lap**, lap*.

---

The [Wiktionary etymology entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/war#Etymology) for "war" has

> Compare Latin versus (“against, turned”), past participle of vertere (“turn, change, overthrow, destroy”). More at worse, wurst.

This seems to suggest a relation between PIE *wers (root of war, worse) and *wert (root of versus and possibly wurst). I'm also asking about *werb since it is so similar to *wert in sound and meaning.

Are any of these 3 roots actually related?

Comment: The relation is that they are three PIE roots that seem to resemble one another in phonological shape.

Comment: @jlawler added where i got the question. do you think that wiktionary entry is mistaken?

Comment: That comment doesn't really help... I don't know if Wiktionary just happens to be wrong or what, but the point the poster seems to be making there is that if 1) "worse" is from *wers, 2) "versus" is from *wert (through "vertere"), but also 3)  "worse" is related to "versus", which is Wiktionary's claim... then *wers must also be related to *wert.

Comment: @LjL that comment came before I added the wiktionary citation.

Comment: Wikitionary is obviously not a one person thing, you  can't apply a=b and b=C so a=C here. Because b and C might have been contributed by different people.

Answer (score 6):

The currently fashionable theory is that *wer is a root, and -s, -t, -b are "extensions". What is still missing is an explanation of what exactly the function of these "extensions" is supposed to be.

Comment: could you point me in the direction of any references?

Comment: @Colin. This, perhaps, as an overview: https://iling.spb.ru/confs/root_extensions.pdf

Comment: Very interesting--but it doesn't seem to bear directly on this issue.

Comment: Those are abstracts from a workshop. There's mention of: \*werh3dh- > PGrm \*(s)wor-dh- "to observe" on p. 25; IE root enlargements \*-s- and \*-d- on p. 29; again \*-dh- on p. 31, as "clusters of plain voices [sic!] stops + laryngeals", stating the obvious comparison to \*dheh1- next to other scenarios; *Agentivität* vs *Inagentivität*, without cited examples (p. 34); preverbals modifying verbal aspect perfect vs imperfect in Germanic vs Balto-Slavic and Celtic (p. 36). A few highly respected names in there, many bibliographical references; certainly underlines the answer's noted uncertainty!

Comment: I'd go one step further and try to isolate \*-r- e.g. as L *re* "back, again", *rota* "wheel"; which of course leads to reductio ad absurdum, if we are thus left with \*w-, but that's not unreasonable and allows further comparisons; too many, alas.